# Error in Keras.Reshape layer when last batch of sample does not reach batch_size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello people of the internet,

I am quite new and I have made a simple tensorflow model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(Input(batch_shape=(batch_size = 100, 50, 100, 12)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters= 1, kernel_size = (1,1))

model.add(Reshape((50, 100)))

model.add(LSTM(units=16))

model.add(Dense(1))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'Adam')
```

I have checked the model summary and the dimensions seem to be sane.
However, the problem occurs when I finish running the model for 1 epoch. The reason is that I have less than 100 samples in the last batch as my total sample size is not a multiple of 100. As such the `Reshape` layer gets the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 460000 values, but the requested shape has 500000
     [[node sequential_18/reshape_9/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-48-fa829a07c08d>:26) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_167420]
```

I have technically managed to fix the error by changing the batch_size to a factor of the total sample size. However, I am still wondering if there is a more robust solution that could allow the `Reshape` layer to take in variable batch sizes.

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Oh never mind, I realise if I don't specify the batch size in input, it is fine. So instead of `batch_shape`, use `shape` in the `input` layer!